# How to specify a field as float while converting CSV to Json in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm converting csv to newline delimited json with

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('input.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('output.json', 'w')

reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Input:

```
firstname,secondname,id,marks
John,Doe,001,50
George,Washington,002,100
```

Output:

```
{"firstname": "John", "secondname": "Doe", "id": "001", "marks": "50"}
{"firstname": "George", "secondname": "Washington", "id": "002", "marks": "100"}
```

Pretty good. But a search application I'm using rejects to upload the file because I already defined "marks" field as float in the schema. It accepts only if I remove quotation marks around the number field. So I require output to be:

Desired Output:

```
{"firstname": "John", "secondname": "Doe", "id": "001", "marks": 50}
{"firstname": "George", "secondname": "Washington", "id": "002", "marks": 100}
```

Is there a way I can specify a field as float/string while converting csv to json? (I can get away by remapping schema with marks as string, but I'll lose "sort by marks" option in the application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting one dict entry to float:

```
row["marks"] = float(row["marks"])
```

Integrated in your code:

```
for row in reader:
    row["marks"] = float(row["marks"])
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Also see: [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0):

Seeming `a` is one of your dictionaries, you can try:

```
for x in a.keys():
  if str(a[x]).isdigit():
    a[x] = int(a[x])
 
print(a)
```